# Remove XML attribute from string

Tags: regex, string

A have a string like `'<node attr="some_value">'`. How to remove `attr="some_value"` from this string? I know only `attr` attribute name and don't know `"some_value"` value.
P.S. I'm using JavaScript but solution for any language will be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Needs jquery.

```
var xml = '<node attr="some_value">';
var newXml = $(xml).removeAttr('attr');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Regexs to play with XML is begging for disaster down the line. I'd use built in Xml functionality to do this.

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_removeattribute.asp)

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book');

document.write(x[0].getAttribute('category')); document.write("<br />");

x[0].removeAttribute('category');

document.write(x[0].getAttribute('category'));
```

Where the XML is

```
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 0):

classic solution : use String functions, for exemple :

```
str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("attr")-1) + ">"
```